Many addons are missing from Blender 4.2. How do I install addons in Blender 4.2?
How do I install LoopTools for Blender 4.2? I remember this was part of previous Blender versions.

CGDive has just posted a comprehensive tutorial about the new Extensions system and how to use it here.

Some addons that were previously built-in like LoopTools are now classified as Extensions. You can find them now under Edit > Preferences > Get Extensions but you need online access. See Changes to Add-on and Themes Bundling (4.2 onwards) for more information.

From Blender 4.2 onwards there will be no external add-ons repository
integrated with the Blender source code. Instead these add-ons will
either move into their own repository and shared on the extensions
website or exceptionally, be converted into a “core” add-on.


The third party addons are still installed within the Add-ons tab, by clicking the upper right drop down icon and clicking Install from Disk...

