How can I transfer settings from Blender 4.1 to 4.2?
I recently installed Blender 4.2, but it’s starting with the default factory settings—meaning all my key mappings, shortcuts, and startup preferences are gone. It seems like Blender 4.2 starts from scratch. How can I transfer my settings from the previous version?

Something you might try: if your OS is Windows, I don't know the path for other OS'es, go to Users/"your user name"/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/4.1/config and copy the startup.blend and userpref.blend files into the 4.2 config folder.

@curious_1 This actually worked! Thank you! :)

Each version has a "Load settings from xxx" (the previous version No.) on the initial splash screen when you first start it after installation. I guess you'll have to delete the Config folder and run it again if you want to get that setting screen back.

@curious_1 Note that when transitioning specifically from a version below 4.2 to version 4.2 or above, this will only work for startup.blend but not for addon settings in userpref.blend because the addon installation implementation in 4.2 has changed. Addons are now split into Built-in and the new Extensions as explained in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321746/many-addons-are-missing-from-blender-4-2-how-do-i-install-addons-in-blender-4-2/321748#321748

@HarryMcKenzie apologies if this appears nit-picky. I think it's relevant if someone has the same problem as the OP, especially if they use third-party addons. The userpref.blend will work as you say regarding Blender addons and one needs to do what you say in your linked answer. But, my experience is that if one uses third-party addons they are activated either when using "Import Blender 4.1 Preferences" on installation, or copying and pasting the 4.1 userpref file into 4.2. The new procedure wasn't needed for any of them that I use.

@curious_1 No worries. Thanks for sharing. I havn't tried the "Import Blender 4.1 Preferences" yet. Interesting if that works. But I just shared my experience when I copied the userpref.blend from 4.1 to 4.2 https://i.sstatic.net/AXCXaF8J.png I got lots of built-in and 3rd party addons warnings/errors.
