How to install previous version of the blender preference to the new blender 4.2 version?
How can I install the previous version's preferences like add-ons, themes and settings into the new version? The problem is that I've already uninstalled the earlier version of Blender(which I had installed from the MS Store), and because of that, I can't find the folder for it in the Blender Foundation folder. There is only one folder 4.2(which is the latest version), Is there a way to find or install the previous preferences in this version?

If you actually deleted the prefrences folder when you uninstalled the old version, there's no way to retrieve them because they no longer exist. However, it's worth reading https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-would-i-import-export-blenders-preferences and seeing if they still exist. See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321754/how-to-transfer-settings-from-blender-4-1-to-4-2
