I can't find the add-on, Add Mesh: Extra Objects on Blender 4.2
I'm very new to blender, just downloaded the software an hour ago. I have blender 4.2 downloaded. I'm trying to follow a simple tutorial on youtube but I can't find the add-on Add Mesh: Extra object at all.
I've deleted my file, made a new one and tried to follow different tickets for the same question but nothing is working.  Sorry if this has already be answered, I can't find any resources that has worked for my problem.

See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321746/many-addons-are-missing-from-blender-4-2-how-do-i-install-addons-in-blender-4-2/321748#321748

all extra objects addons are available from the Extensions tab.

In Blender 4.2.2 LTS, it is called 'Extra Mesh Objects' and is listed under 'Get Extensions.' If you search for the old name 'Add Mesh: Extra Objects,' it won't show up on the list.

Apologies for this. There are no extra meshes in Blender 4.2, but there is a way to do this. Here is how:

You need to copy the "add_mesh_extra_objects" folder from Blender 4.0:
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\addons\add_mesh_extra_objects
then paste it to:
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\4.2\scripts\addons_core

This will work, sorry for using 4.0 instead of 4.2.

That's changed in Blender 4.2. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321746/many-addons-are-missing-from-blender-4-2-how-do-i-install-addons-in-blender-4-2/321748#321748

@Faris incorrect answer. please check again with Blender 4.2 as shown by John

@HarryMcKenzie Just edit it.

@Faris That's wrong too! In Blender 4.2 Extra Mesh Objects is under the Get Extensions section of the Preferences and clicking 'Install' will retrieve and install it from the online repository.

@JohnEason No one installed something I just copied the add_extra_meshes folder into blender 4.2 core add-ons folder, and when u restart blender u can find it, check it save preferences, and then it's there

Copying files to your addons folder is how you install addons. But I wouldn't recommend installing an addon from an older version if there's one available for the current Blender, especially when newer versions have significant Python API changes, which is the case of v4.2.

@Faris copying a folder from a previous version is not how you are supposed to install addons, especially addons supplied with Blender. The code is often updated between versions and often won't run on later versions. I detailed where you could find it and how to enable it in version 4.2 in my previous comment.

As all others already said, this is not how you should install addons. Especially when there are drastical changes between versions - some are obvious, some might be deeper in the code so you probably won't see what happened between versions. The Extra Objects in my Blender 4.0 for example are version 0.3.9, in Blender 4.2 they are 0.3.12 already. And comparing the folder properties of the addons, the old version has 568 KB in 29 files and 1 folder, the new version is 1.12 MB in 88 files and 7 folders. So in the best case you just have less data, in the worst bugs and non-functional parts.
