lightwave export (.mdd) completely missing in 4.2?
I need to export a cloth sim to keyframes, and I believe this was done using the lightwave export add-on. However, I cannot seem to find this in Preferences or elsewhere?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321746/many-addons-are-missing-from-blender-4-2-how-do-i-install-addons-in-blender-4-2. Search 'mdd' under Preferences > Get Extensions.
