Collections Manager Won't Show In Interface
I accidentally closed my collections manager and for the life of me I absolutely cannot get it to reopen. I've tried pressing M, Ctrl + M,  and Ctrl + G and still nothing.


Do you perhaps mean the Outliner? You seem to bee in full screen, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/accidentally-hit-toggle-full-screen-how-do-i-exit/55995#55995

No, I believe it's called the Collections Manager. It looks like this...file:///Users/jackieedmond/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202024-10-11%20at%201.32.09%20PM.png

We can't see files on  your desktop, see How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

Do you mean this addon Collection Manager? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321746/many-addons-are-missing-from-blender-4-2-how-do-i-install-addons-in-blender-4-2/321748#321748
